# Identities or inequalities for $\lfloor$(a + b)/d$\rfloor$ (for integers a, b and d; d > 0)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm keen to know of any potentially useful identities or inequalities involving the expression $\,\lfloor$ *(a + b) / d* $\rfloor\,$, where $\;$*a, b, d $\in$ Z; d $\gt$ 0*.

From first principles (Euclidean division), all that I've been able to prove so far, is the following:

$\qquad$*$\lfloor$*(a + b)/d$\rfloor\,$$\;=\;$ $\,\lfloor$*a/d*$\rfloor\,$ + $\,\lfloor$*b/d*$\rfloor\,$ + c$\quad$(where c = 0 or c = 1)

So, an obvious inequality would be:

$\qquad$$\,\lfloor$*a/d*$\rfloor\,$ + $\,\lfloor$*b/d*$\rfloor\,$ $\;\le\;$ $\lfloor$(a + b)/d$\rfloor\,$ $\;\le\;$ $\,\lfloor$*a/d*$\rfloor\,$ + $\,\lfloor$*b/d*$\rfloor\,$ + 1

Are there any known potentially useful identities or inequalities for $\lfloor$*(a + b)/d*$\rfloor\,$ other than the above? (I couldn't find any after searching the web for just under an hour!)

Comment: What does $a|d + b|d$ mean?  What does $a|d = c|d$ mean?  $a|d$ isn't a number or even a class of number.  It is a statement about two numbers.  What does "2 divides into 6 evenly plus 5 divides into 45 evenly" mean?  what does "2 divides into 6 equals 5 divides into 10" mean?

Comment: @fleablood By *a div d*, what I mean is the quotient obtained upon dividing *a* by *d* (integer division).  So, *a = (a div d) d + (a mod d)* , where *a mod d* is the remainder obtained in the aforementioned division.  Apologies if the notation I'm using is unorthodox.

Comment: Unorthodox is right!  Google the floor function.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for setting me right regarding the correct notation to use!  I've edited my question accordingly.